# Watson Speech to Text Android

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I am using the example code from IBM's github for Speech To Text but this line is giving me problems. android studio throws an error saying that i don't need the "capture" argument but when i remove it, i get an error when i run it that the audio cannot be null.

```
speechService.recognizeUsingWebSocket(capture, getRecognizeOptions(), new MicrophoneRecognizeDelegate());
```

it is used in this part

```
private void recordMessage() {
    //mic.setEnabled(false);
    speechService = new SpeechToText();
    speechService.setUsernameAndPassword(STT_username, STT_password);
    speechService.setEndPoint("https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api");


    if(listening != true) {
        capture = microphoneHelper.getInputStream(true);
        InputStream myInputStream = new MicrophoneInputStream(true);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                try {


                    speechService.recognizeUsingWebSocket(capture, getRecognizeOptions(), new MicrophoneRecognizeDelegate());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    showError(e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
        listening = true;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Listening....Click to Stop", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {
        try {
            microphoneHelper.closeInputStream();
            listening = false;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Stopped Listening....Click to Start", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you request the permission? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECORD_AUDIO

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer but just in case anyone needs this ..

update your call to :

```
speechService.recognizeUsingWebSocket(getRecognizeOptions(capture),new MicrophoneRecognizeDelegate());
```